# scale and ratio : try to find x,y,width,height

Tags: geometry

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbQSu.png

I have to boxes with same ratio.

How can I find position x,y and width,height in the second box ?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are positions of what? If this is taking place on the Cartesian plane, where is the origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying the small $x$-value ($10$) with the ratio between the two heights should do the trick. And likewise for everything else. So $x$ in the larger box would be twice $10\times\frac{100}{50} = 20$.