# Find updated X, Y, Width, and Height

Tags: geometry

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbQSu.png) is based off a previous question that wasn't fully answered. I do not have enough points to reply to the question, and the [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242572/scale-and-ratio-try-to-find-x-y-width-height) is pretty old.

I have an image with $X, Y$, Width, and Height. The previous answer said to "Multiplying the small $x$-value ($10$) with the ratio between the two heights".

Did he really mean to multiply by the width ratio? If not, does that mean to get $y$-value you multiply by the ratio between the two widths? Does the same apply for width and height? Also does it matter if the desired dimensions are larger or smaller?

Comment: In that diagram, I think $x$ is the vertical dimension corresponding to height (or since it increases downwards, perhaps "depth")

Answer (score 1):

In the example both scaling factors in $x$ and $y$ direction (width and height) are equal to $2$, so it doesn't matter.

In general, when width is scaled by $\alpha$ and height by $\beta$, you multiply all $x$-coordinates by $\alpha$ and all $y$-coordinates by $\beta$. (Assuming the $x$-axis is horizontal and the $y$-axis is vertical.)